# Test if there is a minimum amount of mobs within a radius without a scoreboard?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft 1.12.2

I want to create a re-spawn system for the enemies in the different map areas. I could use a counter on a scoreboard with an armor stand as the entity but with all the areas I have in my map I think it would cause lag.

For example:

I want 5 zombies in an area of 20 block, the player comes and kills 2 of them. The player leaves. The system re-spawns the dead mobs making a total of 5 again.

I know how to test if the player left the area:

```
/testfor @a[r={radius}]
```

But what I don't know how to test for the minimum amount of enemies without a scoreboard i can't make it.

I tried the Count modifier in the selector but I realized that is not how it works. I tried something like this:

```
/testfor @e[type={entity},r={radius},c={amount}]
```

but it would activate when there was only 1.

In the end:

Is there a way too test for a minimum amount of mobs in a certain radius without a scoreboard?

Comment: You should specify more clearly that you are in 1.12.2, since that changes a lot of things about possible answers. And it's not the scoreboard that's the enemy of performance, it's the holders, aka armour stands and even those a tiny amount. I'm not sure whether something like `execute if score` for fake players in 1.13 can be complety mimicked in 1.12, I don't think you can.

Comment: sorry I actually didn't realized I'll edit the post

Answer (score 1):

Could you use tags? Here's a method I whipped up:

You'll want to tag the zombies one by one until you can't tag them anymore, then detect where the tagging stopped. Let's assume you have a maximum of 5 zombies. Repeat these two commands 5 times in a command block, each time adding the number in the first command by 1:

```
scoreboard players tag @e[type=zombie,tag=!tagged] add 1
scoreboard players tag @e[type=zombie,tag=1] add tagged
```

This machine will stop tagging zombies once the number tag is equal to the amount of zombies. You can then use these testfor commands to see if there are 3 but not 4 zombies, for example.

```
testfor @e[type=zombie,tag=3]
testfor @e[type=zombie,tag=4]
```

Combine with chain command blocks/comparators (whichever is best for you in your situation) until you have the machine you need. And of course you'll have to remove the tags 1 2 3 4 5 and tagged from all zombies, and combine with the radius condition.